# Mapbox Distance Matrix API returns all zeroes

Tags: http, mapbox

I'm trying to implement the Mapbox Distance Matrix API as an alternative to Google, since it was becoming too expensive. I've tried to reduce the example to something minimal, with only two values:

```
{
  code: "Ok",
  distances: [
    [
      0,
      0
    ]
  ],
  durations: [
    [
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0
    ]
  ],
  destinations: [
    {
      distance: 404951.186070298,
      name: "",
      location: [
        48.761423,
        5.731594
      ]
    },
    {
      distance: 402983.402982556,
      name: "",
      location: [
        48.761423,
        5.731594
      ]
    }
  ],
  sources: [
    {
      distance: 401905.604376238,
      name: "",
      location: [
        48.761423,
        5.731594
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I see that the coordinates of the values are the same, even though they do not match the input coordinates from my URL, which are `52.08515,4.2826;52.11703,4.28716;52.11736,4.28939`. The problem persists with all modes of transportation. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format is lon,lat - not lat,lon - I made the same mistake but the docs are correct.

Comment: I have the same problem.but all the values are not zero. just some of them.how can I fix this issue?

Comment: Thank you I was searching for this answer for 3 days now